Angular 17 - Chart not updating when using apexchart to update scatter chart using an SSE that brings the data stream
I am using Angular 17, when ever the data stream is triggered from an SSE which is generally for every slipt second, I am updating my apex chart. I am using this for populating the real time data.
I have tried setInterval, throttleTime of rxjs, triggering change detection manually after chartoptions update
constructor(){
const now = Date.now();
    const oneDayAgo = now - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hours in milliseconds
    
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Scatter Data',
          type: 'scatter',
          data: [], // This will be dynamically populated based on SSE data
          fillColor: 'black'
        },
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'scatter', // Change the chart type to scatter
        zoom: { type: 'xy' },
        animations: {
          enabled: true,
          easing: 'linear',
          speed: 500,
        },
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime', // Change to datetime for time-based plotting
        min: oneDayAgo, // 24 hours ago
        max: now, // Current time
        labels: {
          formatter: (value: moment.MomentInput) => moment(value).format('HH:mm'), // Format as hours and minutes
        },
        tickAmount: 50, // You might want to adjust the tick amount based on granularity
      },
      yaxis: [
        {
          title: {
            text: 'Scatter Value', // Adjusted to represent scatter data
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 50, // Set according to expected range, adjust as needed
          axisBorder: {
            show: true,
            color: '#007BC0',
          },
        },
      ],
      grid: {
        show: true,
        padding: { left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10 },
      },
    };
}
 ngOnInit(): void {
    // Subscribe to SSE with throttling
 this.sseSubscription = this.sseService.throttledEvents$.pipe(
   throttleTime(10000) // Throttle to one event 10 second
   ).subscribe(
     (event: any) => this.updateChart(event.data);,
   (error: any) => {
      console.error('SSE error:', error);
      }
     );    
  }

updateChart(data: any): void {
    const currentTime = new Date(Date.now()).getTime();

    // Update chart data only if it's within the last 24 hours
    
    // const itemTime = new Date(item[0]);
     const resultDate = new Date(data.RESULT_DATE_LOCAL);

      if (resultDate.getTime() >= this.chartOptions.xaxis.min && 
      resultDate.getTime() <= this.chartOptions.xaxis.max) {
   this.chartOptions.series[0].data.push([resultDate.getTime(), data.RESULT_VALUE]);
    // To refresh the chart, reassign the series to trigger a re-render
    console.log("chart refresh");
 
    this.chartOptions = { ...this.chartOptions };
}


My HTML
   <div id="chart">
  <apx-chart 
  [series]="chartOptions.series"
  [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
  [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
  [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
  [grid]="chartOptions.grid"
  [title]="chartOptions.title"
  [markers]="chartOptions.markers"
  [colors]="chartOptions.colors"
></apx-chart>
</div>

